# Posh-SSH and Cisco Gear

Tags: powershell, ssh, cisco, posh-ssh

I've been working on doing some scripting with Powershell and the Posh-SSH module.  I'm connecting to mainly Cisco gear, but have some other network gear as well.  My issue seems to be that I can connect to the gear just fine, but my commands don't seem to run.  I've attempted Invoke-SSHCommand as well as creating New-SSHShellStream.  What is odd is if I open Powershell and step through each command manually, it appears to work just fine, but for some reason running in a script doesn't produce the results I'm looking for.

I have found that plink.exe works just fine, but I'd really rather code all this from Powershell if possible.  Is there something I'm missing with these network devices that might be different than a Linux server?

Code:
`New-SSHSession -ComputerName $fw-ip -Credential (Get-Credential) -Verbose<br/>
 $session = Get-SSHSession -Index 0<br/>
 $stream = $session.Session.CreateShellStream("dumb", 0, 0, 0, 0, 1000)<br/>
 $stream.Write("show ver")<br/>
 $stream.Read()`

What I get back:
`Type help or '?' for a list of available commands.<br/>
 FW/Admin>`

Comment: Are you getting any error messages or does the script seem to complete successfully but nothing happens?  also can you post a sample of your code?

Comment: Sorry, trying to answer your question, but I can't figure out the formatting for the code to post on here.  Give me just a minute.

Comment: Ok so it looks like the command is getting sent but the device isn't recognizing it, it's possible that there is something odd about the way that the session recognizes the incomplete "show ver" command, can you try running the full "show version" instead and let me know how it goes?

Comment: When I run the full version, I get nothing back at all.  And you're correct, it would appear that the commands are not being run at all.  Thanks for the help.  I appreciate it.

Comment: So getting nothing back at all when running "show version" as opposed to "show ver" is pretty interesting, it would seem to mean that the command is running, or at least not failing, since the stream is interactive maybe the command has not yet output data yet when you are calling the read()?  maybe try including a start-sleep of a second or two between the write() and read()?

Comment: Boom!  That was it.  It was driving me nuts, because I could past each line from the script into my Powershell window and would get back what I was expecting.  Thanks so much for the assist.  Now, how do I vote your comment/answer up?

Comment: Awesome, happy I coudld help! I've formatted my comments as an answer which you can upvote/accept if you have a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after working with you in the comments it looks like there were two problems, the first being that the SSH shell supported by the SSH.NET library does not seem to support partial commands, swapping "Show Ver" to "Show Version" corrected that.  In addition the command was taking a bit longer to run than the script was waiting before calling its read() on the stream, which can be fixed by adding a `start-sleep -seconds 5` between the write() and the read().  If you are planning to use this with commands that may take longer or where you are not sure how long they will take you may want to look into some additional handling that checks to see if the command is done by checking the dataavailable property or creating a listener for the DataReceived event but if your keeping things simple a basic timer will work great for you.